# Is it a good idea to always send Cache-Control: must-revalidate along with Last-Modified

Tags: http, caching, header, last-modified

I just read this [article](http://www.webscalingblog.com/performance/caching-http-headers-last-modified-and-etag.html) and in the author's discussion of the Last-Modified HTTP header he recommends that Cache-Control: must-revalidated also be sent.  He states:

> What if server doesn’t send
>   Cache-Control: must-revalidate? Then
>   modern browsers look at profile
>   setting or decide on their own whether
>   to send conditional request. So we
>   better to send Cache-Control to make
>   sure that browser sends conditional
>   request.

So, my question is, what's wrong with letting the browser decide? And why would we want to blindly override a browser's profile setting?  I understand that there may be situations when we want to force revalidation but should it always be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your usage.

I'm "with you" for the most part, because on the one hand you're shooting yourself in the foot since you're basically throwing out the advantage of avoiding a round-trip in the first place (caching should avoid a round-trip if possible, then avoid sending content if possible, and then give up and send content, and this author is removing the first gateway if you force the browser to conditionally check before serving from its cache).

On the other hand, maybe you hate funny cache invalidation strings in your code, i.e "main.css?v=2" and want the browser to ask, so you have the opportunity to check a cached ETag on your server and invalidate. That seems like kind of a crummy reason, but I can see it being useful for CMS systems or when you don't have control of the URI.